# How to set zoom control option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

using `react-google-maps`, my following option for changing the position of zoom is not working

```
<GoogleMap
defaultZoom={5}
defaultCenter={{ lat: 22.845625996700075, lng: 78.9629 }}
options={{
  gestureHandling:'greedy',
  zoomControlOptions:'TOP_RIGHT',
  streetViewControl:false,
  fullscreenControl:false,
}}
```

>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zoomControlOptions` prop shape from `react-google-maps` type definitions (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts):

```
  /** Options for the rendering of the zoom control. */
  export interface ZoomControlOptions {
    /**
     * Position id. Used to specify the position of the control on the map.
     * The default position is TOP_LEFT.
     */
    position?: ControlPosition;
    style?: ZoomControlStyle;
  }

export enum ControlPosition {
  BOTTOM_CENTER,
  BOTTOM_LEFT,
  BOTTOM_RIGHT,
  LEFT_BOTTOM,
  LEFT_CENTER,
  LEFT_TOP,
  RIGHT_BOTTOM,
  RIGHT_CENTER,
  RIGHT_TOP,
  TOP_CENTER,
  TOP_LEFT,
  TOP_RIGHT
}
```

This should work:

```
<GoogleMap
  defaultZoom={5}
  defaultCenter={{ lat: 22.845625996700075, lng: 78.9629 }}
  options={{
    gestureHandling:'greedy',
    zoomControlOptions: { position: 9 },
    streetViewControl:false,
    fullscreenControl:false,
  }}
>
```

`google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER` has value of `9`

Comment: Somethings wrong mate. it made control disappear. No error though. should it be `google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER` like this but, then it shows error as google not defined.

Comment: It depends whether or not you're using Typescript - `google.maps.ControlPosition` is an exported enum which has numeric values
I should edit my answer then :)

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts

Comment: then, how come this isn't working as position https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts#L360

Comment: It is - it's an enum as well, but different formatting and no comments